# Replace ?id= and .php from url via htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to replace ?id= and .php  with slash / in my post url.

I tried many answers from other questions but did not work for me like this one -

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56411/remove-php-and-id-from-url-and-replace-with-slash/79438

```
Example Url - 
https://example.com/testing/events/news/post.php?id=13/Checking-to-see-if-this-works
```

I want this example url to be like this

```
https://example.com/testing/events/news/post/13/Checking-to-see-if-this-works
```

I used following htaccess code and it removes .php extension from url but can't figure out how to replace ?id= with /

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

output -

```
https://example.com/testing/events/news/post?id=13/Checking-to-see-if-this-works
```

I still can't replace ?id= with /

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Writing that you "tried many answers from other questions" & giving one is clearly not a case of following [ask] about research. Why do you think it is? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: philipxy ! I can list all of the links to answers but it would be very long list. :)

Comment: To "list all of the links to answers" is clearly not a case of following [ask] about research. You clearly haven't paid attention to my rhetorical question or the [help]. Then you wonder why your questions are poorly received? (Rhetorical.)

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(testing/events/news/post)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(post)/(.+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried this code. url changes but It gives 404 error. Perhaps something needs to changed on post.php. since i get id like this -    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located? Is it in `testing/` directory?

Comment: htaccess is located here - 
 /home/username/public_html/testing/events/news/.htaccess

Comment: Anubhava ! Your code works for post page but breaks other php pages when i add this code to it. This code remove .php from all of the pages. may be you could combine this code with your code.  ----   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]   ------

Comment: Posted full .htaccess. Make sure you don't have any other rule when testing.

Comment: It seems to be working. I am just testing more to make sure it did not break any other page urls or create duplicate urls :)